# df вывести элементы колонки colname со значениями меньше 50 или больше 150

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как в датафрейме df вывести элементы колонки colname (числового типа) со значениями меньше 50 или больше 150?
Необходимо получить что-то вроде:

```py
df['colname'][(df['colname']<50)&(df['colname']>150)]
```

Но этот код выдает

```py
Series([], Name: col1, dtype: int64)
```

Comment: думаю, или - и будет трудно :) - *меньше 50 или больше 150*

Comment: `df.loc[(df['colname']<50) | (df['colname']>150), 'colname']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
df.query("colname < 50 or colname > 150")["colname"]
```

или так:

```
df.query("not (50 <= colname <= 150)")["colname"]
```

или поменяйте в вашем коде `&` --> `|`:

```
df.loc[(df["colname"]<50) | (df["colname"]>150), "colname"]
```

Примеры:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   colname       val
0       40  0.895735
1       60  0.073733
2       80  0.832768
3      100  0.249050
4      120  0.640059
5      140  0.017456
6      160  0.921873

In [8]: df.query("colname < 50 or colname > 150")["colname"]
Out[8]:
0     40
6    160
Name: colname, dtype: int64
```

---

```
In [11]: df.query("not (50 <= colname <= 150)")["colname"]
Out[11]:
0     40
6    160
Name: colname, dtype: int64
```

---

```
In [10]: df.loc[(df["colname"]<50) | (df["colname"]>150), "colname"]
Out[10]:
0     40
6    160
Name: colname, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

1. по твоему коду, ты в начале берешь колонку `[colname]` и потом ищешь в series опять `'colname'`, чего там уже нет.
2. кроме того, естественно нужно "или" а не "и"

корректно вначале фильтруешь, а потом берешь нужную колонку

```
df[(df['colname']<50)|(df['colname']>150)]['colname']
```